correct use of getSignaturesForAddress RPC Method
I have the token address for a specific spl token. Is it possible for me to get the latest transactions from the just this mint address? Is there an rpc method which facilitates this.
I'm aware of getSignaturesForAddress RPC Method however I'm not sure how to programmatically provide the correct parameters for it. It seems it requires Account address as base-58 encoded string, how can i get such an address?
To further add to the problem, the token is traded on both Raydium and Pump.fun, so will I need to make some distinction between the two?
I'd appreciate if anyone could shed light on this thanks

account address as base-58 encoded string is in JS for example:
const address = new PublicKey(tokenAddress)
PublicKey is imported from @solana/web3.js
You will get all transactions not only Raydium or pump.fun, also user transferring tokens from a wallet to another for example. It could be a lot of transactions if the token is used by a lot of people.

Thanks for the comment, what is meant by account address? I tried the spl token's mint address but it doesn't seem to work.
If i have the mint address what steps can i take to get the correct account address to query the transaction signatures? Sorry for the noob question
